# Autoload paths and nested services classes crash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-5

I've multiple issues to load / require classes under my `app/services` folder in a Rails 5 project and I'm starting to give up on this issue.

First of all and to be clear, `services/` are simple PORO classes I use throughout my project to abstract most of the business logic from the controllers, models, etc.

The tree looks like this

```
app/
 services/
  my_service/
    base.rb
    funny_name.rb
  my_service.rb  
models/
 funny_name.rb
```

### Failure #1

First, when I tried to use `MyService.const_get('FunnyName')` it got `FunnyName` from my models directory. It does not seem to have the same behavior when I do `MyService::FunnyName` directly though, in most of my tests and changes this was working fine, it's odd.

I realised Rails `config.autoload_paths` does not load things recursively ; it would makes sense that the first `FunnyName` to be catch is the `models/funny_name.rb` because it's definitely loaded but not the other.

That's ok, let's find a workaround. I added this to my `application.rb` :

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '**/')]
```

Which will add all the subdirectories of services into `config.autoload_paths`. Apparently it's not recommended to write things like that since Rails 5 ; but the idea does look right to me.

### Failure #2

Now, when I start my application it crashes and output something like this

> Unable to autoload constant Base, expected
>   /.../backend/app/services/my_service/base.rb to define it (LoadError)

*Names were changed but it's the matching path from the tree I wrote previously*

The thing is, `base.rb` is defined in the exact file the error leads me, which contains something like

```
class MyService
  class Base
  end
end
```

### Poor solution

So I try other workaround, lots of them, nothing ever works. So I end up totally removing the `autoload_paths` and add this directly in the `application.rb`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '**', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
```

Now the `base.rb` is correctly loaded, the `MyService.const_get('FunnyName')` will actually return the correct class and everything works, but it's a disgusting workaround. Also, it has yet not been tested in `production` but it might create problems depending the environment.

Requiring the whole tree from the `application.rb` sounds like a bad idea and I don't think it can be kept this way.

What's the cleanest way to add custom `services/` directory in Rails ? It contains multiple subdirectories and classes with simple names which are also present in other parts of the app (models, `base.rb`, etc.)

How do you avoid confusing the `autoload_paths` ? Is there something else I don't know which could do the trick ? Why did `base.rb` even crash here ?

Comment: Please add one of your service definitions (first line should do it) to your question.

Comment: what do you mean ? should i write what's a service to me ?

Comment: I mean, does `app/services/my_class/base.rb` start like `class MyClass::Base`?

Comment: It's written below, sorry I had to edit it at first because i wasn't highlighted as code

Comment: Oh, I see. That's incorrect. `class MyClass` should be `module MyClass`.

Comment: this is an example ... there would be a `my_class.rb` at the base as well to be more correct, i'll add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Working solution

After deeper investigation and attempts, I realised that I had to `eager_load` the services to avoid getting wrong constants when calling meta functionalities such as `const_get('MyClassWithModelName')`.

But here's is the thing : the classic `eager_load_paths` won't work because for some reason those classes will apparently be loaded before the entire core of Rails is initialized, and simple class names such as `Base` will actually be mixed up with the core, therefore make everything crash.

Some could say "then rename Base into something else" but should I change a class name wrapped into a namespace because Rails tell me to ? I don't think so. **Class names should be kept simple, and what I do inside a custom namespace is no concern of Rails.**

I had to think it through and write down my own hook of Rails configuration. We load the core and all its functionalities and then `service/` recursively.

On a side note, it won't add any weight to the production environment, and it's very convenient for development.

## Code to add

Place this in `config/environment/development.rb` and all other environment you want to eager load without Rails class conflicts (such as `test.rb` in my case)

```
# we eager load all services and subdirectories after Rails itself has been initializer
# why not use `eager_load_paths` or `autoload_paths` ? it makes conflict with the Rails core classes
# here we do eager them the same way but afterwards so it never crashes or has conflicts.
# see `initializers/after_eager_load_paths.rb` for more details
config.after_eager_load_paths = Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '**/')]
```

Then create a new file `initializers/after_eager_load_paths.rb` containing this

```
# this is a customized eager load system
# after Rails has been initialized and if the `after_eager_load_paths` contains something
# we will go through the directories recursively and eager load all ruby files
# this is to avoid constant mismatch on startup with `autoload_paths` or `eager_load_paths`
# it also prevent any autoload failure dû to deep recursive folders with subclasses
# which have similar name to top level constants.
Rails.application.configure do
  if config.respond_to?(:after_eager_load_paths) && config.after_eager_load_paths.instance_of?(Array)
    config.after_initialize do
      config.after_eager_load_paths.each do |path|
        Dir["#{path}/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Works like a charm. You can also change `require` by `load` if you need it.

Comment: Glad you got this working. As to your question: *"should I change a class name wrapped into a namespace because Rails tell me to?"*. One of the Rails mantras is "convention over configuration". So, if you buy into the mantra, then the answer would likely be "yes". But, you've done things the way that works for you. So, nice work!

Comment: but aren't namespaces supposed to be used for that purpose ? split things so you can work on them without worrying about what's outside ?

Answer (score 1):

When I do this (which is in all of my projects), it looks something like this:

```
app
 |- services
 |   |- sub_service
 |   |   |- service_base.rb
 |   |   |- useful_service.rb     
 |   |- service_base.rb
```

I put all common method definitions in `app/services/service_base.rb`:

app/services/service_base.rb

```
class ServiceBase

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  class < self 

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end

end
```

I put any methods common to the `sub_services` in `app/services/sub_service/service_base.rb`:

app/services/sub_service/service_base.rb

```
class SubService::ServiceBase < ServiceBase

    def call

    end

  private

    def a_subservice_method
    end

end
```

And then any unique methods in `useful_service`:

app/services/sub_service/useful_service.rb

```
class SubService::UsefulService < SubService::ServiceBase

    def call
      a_subservice_method
      a_useful_service_method
    end

  private

    def a_useful_service_method
    end

end
```

Then, I can do something like:

```
SubService::UsefulService.call(some: :args)
```

Comment: Alright, but the issue isn't about those, it's more about rails autoloading and customised directories ... the biggest error being `base.rb` apparently can't be defined twice in the same project and a service with the same name of a model - which can occur - has some kind of mismatch ..

Comment: Welp, I guess the point is that if you do it like I showed (which is pretty much the same as the other answer, IMO), then autoloading and customised directories will work flawlessly. But, yes, you are correct. If you begin doing things in unconventional ways, you will run into problems with autoloading and customised directories.

Comment: Well it's not about being unconventional so much, if a service starts to be really complex (i'm saying service but it could be any design pattern) you need to abstract into multiple PORO down the class so it's easily testable, etc. but why would you use "_service" to each one of those internally used subclasses to avoid collision ? Namespaces are supposed to deal with this exact issue. I hope you see what I mean, I don't get why Rails do that, and how to solve it properly .. Still investigating ...

Comment: Defining `class Base` inside of `class MyClass` in the file 'app/services/my_class/base.rb` *is* unconventional, I believe. That file structure, conventionally, expects that `MyClass` is a `module`, not a `class`. Which is what both answers recommend. But, hey, what do I know? BTW, in my projects, I have dozens and dozens of POROs (services, decorators, presenters, managers, etc.) that call each other in endless permutations. For things I use over and over, I extract them into gems. All testable. All quite lovely.

Comment: ... Right a module .. Except for `my_class.rb` on the side of the tree I wrote which could be anything, right ? But, hey, what do I know ? Now if you read carefully and rename `MyClass` by `MyClassService` I match your convention, I highlighted the internal aspect for a reason, did we solve my problem by changing the name ? No we didn't. The issue is a loading problem which could be applied to any subfolder not a "this is a service it should be named like this" one. You all replied out of topic and all read "service" as it was the problem, not even quoting the `const_get` problem.

Comment: I already solved the issue myself, but the solution isn't ideal and I wanted expert opinions to preload those constants in the right place, in the right way. Yes turning things into gem is a good idea but overdone for this example. Also, we talk big corporate project here.

Comment: It seems neither of the answers provide you with a satisfactory solution for autoloading and customized directory structures. I'll look forward to better answers. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, I think I found a working solution today and will post it there at some point if no one has better than that :)

Answer (score 1):

With your tree,

```
app/
 services/
  my_class/
    base.rb
    funny_name.rb
  my_class.rb  
models/
 funny_name.rb
```

services/my_class/base.rb should look similar to:

```
module MyClass
  class Base
```

services/my_class/funny_name.rb should look similar to:

```
module MyClass
  class FunnyName
```

services/my_class.rb should look similar to:

```
class MyClass
```

models/funny_name.rb should look similar to:

```
class FunnyName
```

I say "should look similar to" because class/module are interchangable; Rails is merely looking for these constants to be defined in these locations.

You don't need to add anything to your autoload path. Rails automatically picks up everything in `app`

Anecdotal: With your services directory, it's fairly common to treat their naming convention (both name of file and underlying constant) to be "_service.rb" or "ThingService" — just like how controllers look. Models don't get this suffix because they're treated as first-class objects.

GitLab has some great file structure that is very worth a look at. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce

Comment: Thanks, i know all this, actually all my services classes have "_service.rb" added at the end, but those services can become very complex so i usually create "my_service/" directory and then inside ... that's where it goes wrong. Due to the numbers of classes it can contain, and the fact those classes are called internally to the service, I keep the names simple, like `base.rb` but I started to get weird results when the names match some models, or other classes ... Now i'm wondering how to find a good workaround for this

Comment: The real issue is, if it's namespaced, why is there a problem with name crash ?

Comment: Let me see if I can reproduce it real quick, one sec.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it with a really naive example. If you want to reproduce this in an example Rails app and push it to Github I can give it a look.

Comment: This is the solution, people. Just name your files correctly, and have the correct module and class names in your code, and they will autoload, even in subdirectories.