# Nested Helpers Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to migrate a legacy app from 3 to 4 (and of course I'll go to 5 and 6 next). Basically it is a helper heavy app, and it encapsulates a lot of the logic on helpers.

I have some trouble loading helpers on rails 4 and I think I sorted it out but I seem to be having issues with nested helpers. I'm using the `traceroute` gem to validate that the routes on the routes.rb work properly and I'm coming with some issues there.

Example:

```
uninitialized constant Permissions
/home/app/helpers/permissions/charts_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Charts helper (app/helpers/permissions/charts_helper.rb)

```
module Permissions::ChartsHelper

  ...

end
```

Importing of helpers on `application.rb`:

```
   config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
   # config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/helpers/**/"]
   Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/concerns/**/*.rb"].each { |file| require file[0..-4]}
   Dir["#{config.root}/app/helpers/**/*.rb"].each { |file| require file[0..-4]}
```

(I had to comment out the second line in favor of the 4th line and it seemed to import some helpers but not all)

So basically I'm looking for:

1.) Best way to include these helpers on the applications.rb file
2.) Make the helpers work
3.) Any best practices or other advice that can help me move forward.

Comment: This maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566932/autoload-paths-and-nested-services-classes-crash-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Permissions
  module ChartsHelper
    # ...
  end
end
```

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
> nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
> constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
> module nesting at the point of definition.
> - [the Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide)

Using `::` is not a shorthand for explicit nesting and it requires that Permissions be loaded first to avoid a missing constant error.

```
module Permissions::ChartsHelper
end
# NameError (uninitialized constant Permissions)
```

It also sets the wrong module nesting:

```
FOO = "I'm in the global scope"

module Permissions
  FOO = "I'm Permissions::FOO"
end

module Permissions::ChartsHelper
  puts FOO # I'm in the global scope
  puts Module.nesting.inspect # [Permissions::ChartsHelper]
end
```

In Ruby only the `module` and `class` keywords change the current module nesting.
By contrast if you explicitly nest the modules:

```
FOO = "I'm in the global scope"

module Permissions
  FOO = "I'm Permissions::FOO"
end

module Permissions
  module ChartsHelper
    puts FOO # I'm Permissions::FOO
    puts Module.nesting.inspect # [Permissions::ChartsHelper, Permissions]
  end
end
```