# Error 'Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern' on legacy concerns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As part of some legacy code migration project, my concerns are not working properly. Mainly they're getting the following error: `Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern`

Example of a simple concern:

```
module Archiveable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
    scope :archived, -> { where('archived_at IS NOT NULL') }
    end

  # allows archive date to be set to past, present or future
  # @return [DateTime]
  # @param timestamp [nil|DateTime]
  #
  def archive(timestamp=Time.now)
    self.archived_at = timestamp
  end

  # return whether the set is archived or not
  # @return [Boolean]
  #
  def archived?
    archived_at != nil
  end; alias_method :is_archived?, :archived?

end
```

Example of the only instance where this is called:

```
class Applications::Set < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'applications_sets'
  acts_as_paranoid
  # paper trail?

  include Archiveable
  ...
```

I am loading concerns this way:

```
config.after_eager_load_paths = Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'concerns', '**/')]
```

... and I implement the initializer described here: [Autoload paths and nested services classes crash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566932/autoload-paths-and-nested-services-classes-crash-in-ruby)

Any ideas why I might still be getting this errror?

Comment: `app/models/concerns` is an autoloading root in Rails 4. You don't need to add it to the eager load paths. This code also has the same issue with nested constant declaration as in your previous question.

Comment: max Thanks really appreciate it. I'm trying to understand how this nesting is supposed to be though, if I need to nest classes or if any of them should be modules.